# Equal Height Columns with Cross-Browser CSS

Tags: css, height

I want to have divs of the same height.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

does not work for be because my divs have a border, and the method described assumes, that they have not.

A jQuery solution I could not make work, because my divs resize late because of ajax and menu clicks and I can not find an event for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it seems the plugin doesn't support borders, it does support padding.  Try wrapping them in another div, and then setting a padding of 2px (or however big you want the border) and then just applying a background color to this new div.

Not the most web standards friendly, but it will allow you use the trick.

Comment: Yea - it is a trick. The disadvantage is, whenever I want to reformat I have to think about all of these nested and overlayed divs. While it may work I have doubt that this was in the intention of the designer.

Answer (score 0):

See this blogpost:
http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm. Thank you for this good overview. This supports my assumption, that there is no real solution, just tricks. I did not understand, though, why I could not or should not use tables for layout. I resolved to using tables and for me it works fine.