# Equal height for parallel list items using CSS

Tags: css, list

I have this situation   [click here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Venugopal/ZbtRA/1/)

according to text length, the buttons height changes. when it does I want its parallel button height made equal to that of first one (not of all buttons but of only its parallel button).

Comment: Take a look at this question, perhaps it helps. The OP wants columns with same height BUT with borders... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817913/equal-height-columns-with-cross-browser-css

Comment: I believe javacript would be your best answer here

Comment: @Arkana I have checked all those examples before but I don't find anything similar to this situation.

Comment: @Doug That will be easy I guess. But I want to do it with only CSS.

Comment: @VenuGopal Ops, sorry... I think you want just that, equal columns.... perhaps you could explain your desired behaviour a bit more, please?

Comment: @Arkana As you can see in the fiddle, there are four list items. Among them, 2nd list item contain more text compared to others so its height increased to accommodate the whole text. Now I want the first list item height made equal to that of second list item.

Comment: Based on the current HTML mark-up, what you want can't be done using only CSS.  Essentially, you want the 1st `<li>` element to adjust its height based on the height of the 2nd `<li>` element.  CSS does not work that way. If you are willing to adjust the HTML, it might be possible.

Comment: @Marc I got equal heights for all list items with 'display:table-row' for 'ul' and 'display:table-cell' for 'li' but all list items comes in a single row. I couldn't break them to display in multiple lines.

Comment: You would need to generate multiple table-row's and to do that, you need to alter the HTML to achieve that similar to the answer provided by @Doug Which is why I am asking, can we change the HTML?

Comment: of course... you could always go "retro" and lay it out with tables :)

Comment: Aaargh, I can't..... I think without changing markup or using JS it's impossible achieve this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this in one of two ways - either using jQuery ([fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Wn8DV/) - notice that you would need to wrap each button pair in its own `ul` - if you don't do this the jQuery would be more complicated) or by cheating and dropping in a background image which gives the effect of what you're after - this could be done, again, by wrapping each button pair in its own `ul` and dropping in a background image containing vertical lines to wrap them - you could then 'cap off' each column by adding starting and finishing `li` elements with graphical end caps.

I understand that you want to go with CSS only, but I can't think of a way that could be done. There may be something you could do involving careful balancing of max-height, min-height, and height... but I can't think of how that would work at the moment.